# Grep sed command

Tags: sed, grep

Can anybody say me what does this command mean? Thanks

```
grep  -h -o "\@string\/\(\w*\)" * -R | sed "s!@string\/\(\w*\)!\1!p" | sort | uniq > ..\AndroidProject1\tmp_used_strings.txt
```

Comment: It manipulates some data.

Comment: From where did you get the command and which parts of it are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will give you the list of string which is used in android layout xml file.

```
grep  -h -o "\@string\/\(\w*\)" * -R
```

-R - Recursive searching

-h - no file name

-o - print only matched part of string

This command will give you the exact match string. Then, you are piping this output to input of sed command.

```
sed "s!@string\/\(\w*\)!\1!p"
```

This command will parse the input and separate the name. Then, sorting the result and store the uniq values to the file.

For more information about options, see the man page of command.